# Define an entity for a denormalized table in JPA (acts as aggregator)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm getting crazy trying to find the way to map the following legacy (unmodifiable) table

```
 id| ref | lang | text
 ---------------------
 1   666    en     hello
 2   666    es     hola
 3   666    de     hallo
 4   667    en     goodbye
 5   667    es     adios
 6   667    de     tschuss
```

into an entity something like

```
@Id
@Column
private Long ref;

??@Column
??Map<String,String> textByLang;
```

Is it possible? I tried everything

Comment: Map represent a collection valued association. An Entity represents a row and if you design your entity this way, Map only contains a single key-value pair for each row. I think you should re-consider your approach.

Comment: @AsSiDe Sorry, I forgot to consider that placing Id (by mistake) the example is completely senseless. Please recheck the updated explnation

Comment: It's Same, I suggest use Embeddable Instead of Map.

Comment: Embeddable does not aggregates columns, right?

Comment: And, embeddable is meant to be part of the base table. I need a join someway, with a non-unique fk

Answer (score 1):

It's hard, because you're breaking ORM here. From my experience, usually it's not worth the effort.

If it's absolutely necessary, I would suggest not mapping `lang` and `text` at all, marking your `textByLang` as `@Transient`, and using native query to map the results to intermediate entity.

```
List<IntermediateText> results = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT ref, lang, text from Table t", IntermediateText.class).getResultList();

Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> texts = new HashMap<>();

for (IntermediateTextt : results) {
    texts.putIfAbsent(t.getId(), new HashMap<>()).put(t.getLang(), t.getText());
}

// Create your actual objects here
```

Also, if possible, please take a look at (nonJPA) JDBCTemplate:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html